# boot.log created with permissions 644 instead of 600

Tags: boot, redhat-enterprise-linux, syslog

My `rsyslog.conf` file has this line in it.

```
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
$FileCreateMode 0600
```

I also have

```
$FileCreateMode 0600
local7.* /var/log/boot.log
```

Yet after every reboot the file permissions of `/var/log/boot.log` are still changed to `644`. Every other file has permissions `600`. Does anyone know what would cause this?